Spaces involving time: compact embedding
We know that if $ a, b \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ p > 1 $, then $ W^{1,p}((a, b)) $ is compactly embedded in $C^{0,\alpha}([a, b]) $ for every $\alpha < 1 - \frac{1}{p} $.
From this, how can I prove that $W^{1,2}(0,T;L^2((0,1)) $ is compactly embedded in $C([0,T],L^2(0,1))$?

It is simply not. Let $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X := W^{1, 2}\big(0, T; L^2(0, 1)\big)$ be given by an orthonormal set in $L^2$ (see e.g. this), i.e. $u_k(t, x) := \sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi kx)$ for $x \in (0, 1)$ and $t \in (0, T)$. That is clearly bounded in $X$ and like in the linked post you can prove that it is not precompact in $X$.
To find out which subspaces of $C\big([0, T]; L^2(0, 1)\big)$ are compact, you could consider the paper "Compact sets in the space L^p(0, T; B)" by Jacques Simon. Especially the Ascoli Theorem should be interesting to you.
You certainly need some sort of spatial compactness that you did not assume.
